# Rendering 3d in AE CS6 is blurry

Tags: after-effects, video-quality, 3d, animation-rendering

I'd like to seek help here about rendering in AE CS6 ...

I'm a noob by the way, I just finished a few 4sec animation and have no problem rendering non-3d compositions...

But my first 3d composition consisting of multiple pre-compositions: 2 non-3d text composition and 1 composition that contains multiple shapes as 3d layers (ray-traced 3d not classic) renders "blurry" or maybe at a very low resolution..

During normal playback in the composition view, everything is sharp.

During render at the render queue (and the actual output video), the 3d shapes are low-res (blurry) but the normal non-3d text are sharp

Render settings are all default except for:

1. 32bit color depth
2. H.264 (but I also tried lossless AVI)
3. Bitrate at 8, 10, 12 (same output)

Note (I don't know if this matters):

1. I tried using both motion blur at on and off
2. I used time stretch to increase the speed of the 3d composition

[image]

This the quality if played normally in the composition view

[image]

And this is the result after rendering to video file

Please help......